# Read nvarchar data into DateTimeOffset in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have `nvarchar` values with the following format

```
10:27:32.357 +03 Aug 31 2022
```

How to convert those to `DatetimeOffset` variables in T-SQL?

I have to deal with huge amounts of data, so I want to avoid rebuild the value as segments and then use DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS.

Comment: Is fixing the system that sends the data (in that terrible format) not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the **one** example we have, and assuming your dates are always in the format `hh:mm:ss.nnn [+-]tzoffset MMM dd yyyy` (which is honestly an awful format) you could do something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @BadDateString nvarchar(50) = N'10:27:32.357 +03 Aug 31 2022';

SELECT CONVERT(datetimeoffset(3),CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,RIGHT(@BadDateString,11)),120)+'T'+REPLACE(LEFT(@BadDateString,16),' ','') + ':00')
```

I strongly suggest, however, that you fix the problem by having the application that is sending this data in this format as a strongly typed date and time (`datetimeoffset`) value in the first place; T-SQL's forté isn't strong at string manipulations like like.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to deal with this awful format as is. so I was wondering if there is any other method without segmentations. Thank you for your fast response.

Comment: If it were that easy, you would have found the style when you looked at the documentation for `CONVERT`, @MohammedAlsakkaf .

Comment: I was thinking about the FORMAT function that converts datetime to any nvarchar format. So I guess there will be an inverse for its functionality.

Comment: `FORMAT` is for *formatting* a value when presented as a string, not converting it from a format to a data type. The use of `FORMAT` in T-SQL is generally not recommended either, as its CLR implementation is far from optimal and can have significant performance impacts. The above answer is likely one of the more succinct solutions. though, again, having the application using strongly typed date and time data types in the first place would be the best solution.

Comment: Larnu Finally, i go back to your suggestion thank you